# python turtle module on key

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

so this is from a website but its supposed to be so that when you press the arrow keys it draws a line in the direction of the arrow keys but it wouldnt work it would always say that there was a error in a different file so please help also heres the error code

```
    File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
  turtle.onkey(up,'up')
File "<string>", line 8, in onkey
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1395, in onkey
  self._onkeyrelease(fun, key)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 686, in _onkeyrelease
  self.cv.bind("<KeyRelease-%s>" % key, eventfun)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 417, in bind
  self._canvas.bind(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1383, in bind
  return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1337, in _bind
  self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
```

_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "up"

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import Screen


tim = turtle.Turtle()
tim.speed(0)
tim.width(5)

color = ['red', 'blue', 'green','purple','yellow','orange','black']

def up():
    tim.setheading(90)
    tim.forward(100)

def down():
    tim.setheading(270)
    tim.forward(100)

def left():
    tim.setheading(180)
    tim.forward(100)
def right():
    tim.setheading(0)
    tim.forward(100)

def clickleft(x,y):
    tim.color(random.choice(colors))

def clickright(x,y):
    tim.stamp

turtle.listen()

turtle.onscreenclick(clickleft, 1)
turtle.onscreenclick(clickright, 3)

turtle.onkey(up,'up')
turtle.onkey(down,'down')
turtle.onkey(left,'left')
turtle.onkey(right,'right')

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you add the full text of the error?

Comment: here was the yt vid i followed it on https://youtu.be/HRKQlEfEMCA

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks. We can't help you without them.

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct, the keysyms in this case are `'Up'`, `'Down'`, etc., not `'up'`, `'down'`, etc.  But even if you fix that, the code is still broken several ways:  you invoke `random.choice()` but there is no `import` of the random module;  you declare `color` but you use `colors`; the `stamp()` call is missing its parentheses.

Here's a rework of your code with the above fixes and other changes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black']

def up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(100)

def down():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(100)

def left():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.forward(100)

def right():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(100)

def clickleft(x, y):
    turtle.color(choice(COLORS))

def clickright(x, y):
    turtle.stamp()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.width(5)

screen = Screen()

screen.onkey(up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(down, 'Down')
screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

screen.onclick(clickleft, 1)
screen.onclick(clickright, 3)

screen.mainloop()
```

> this is from a website

Given the sloppy `import` statements, I suggest you never go back there.

Comment: Ridiculous? You're importing the same things in your code

Comment: @OneCricketeer, my `import` loads a class and a function that returns a singular instance.  The OP's three imports loads the entire library, then separately loads a class and a function that returns a singular instance, both of which were already accessable via `turtle.`.  Further, the author of the code is enabling both the *functional* API and *object oriented* API, mixing of which tends to lead to bugs.  My `import` only enables the object oriented API, blocking the functional one.  I guess *sloppy* would have been a better description than *ridiculous*.  I'll fix.